# android: UI on real device problem

Tags: android, user-interface

I wrote simple aplication for android. It works great in emulator. But when I installed it on real device (htc wildfire) then the interface became ugly. Except that it works good. TextViews look fine but the buttons, sprinners and list items look bad. Button corners seem wretched. All the lists (list view and list preference have no delimeter(line) between rows! When I scroll a bit the delimeter appears). Why?

Comment: Is the emulator resolution the same as phone resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified a `targetSdkVersion` in the `uses-sdk` tag in your manifest? If you haven't, Android will assume your app does not know about newer platform versions with different screen sizes/densities and run your app with compatibility scaling.

You should always set `targetSdkVersion` to the newest version of Android that you are targeting. This helps let Android know what compatibility behaviors to use for your app if things changed in newer versions. `targetSdkVersion` can be greater than `minSdkVersion`, meaning your app knows how to take newer platform features into account while remaining compatible with a minimum version.

Comment: Opps... no... thought it wasn't so important

Answer (score 2):

The buttons probably become stretched because you're not using 9 patch images. Here's a good tutorial on 9 patch images http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Regarding the list view, you might want to set this field inside listview in your xml file
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000". That might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, screen density is different on the device. Instead of specifying sizes in pixels (`px`), use `sp` for font size and `dp` for everything else. This way they will scale properly.